# How to use remote microphone on Remote Desktop

Tags: terminal, desktop, services, remote, microphone

I wish to connect to a remote Windows 7 PC that has a microphone, and use that local microphone (on the destination PC) in recording applications.  Unfortunately whenever I connect on Remote Desktop, the remote PC's local microphones become hidden and disabled.  Remote Desktop seems to force using the source computer's microphone with redirection, without an option to use the remote PC's microphone  Isn't there a way to enable using the remote PC's microphone?  I don't get why this should be so hard.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Microsoft Remote Desktop is doing the right thing, when you are remotely connecting to the remote PC, the remote PC is LOCKED. If someone is sitting in front of that PC, they will get a locked screen or login page, so the other side can't use the microphone anyway. Ms Remote Desktop does not allow you to 'eavesdrop' on the remote PC microphone for you to listen in.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use Remote Desktop in the "eavesdrop" mode by using the remote microphone.  Why isn't this possible?

Comment: Because the idea of "Remote Desktop" is you are working where you are, using your physical hardware, but using the remote PC resources. I'm not sure why you wanted to eavesdrop on the remote computer, but TeamViewer MAY be able to do what you want. You remote connect to the remote PC, and then initiate Voice over IP, and you MAY be able eavesdrop the remote PC.. but I have not tested this so I can't say for sure this will work. Note: Connected via TeamViewer IS visible. So whoever on the remote machine will see that you are connected.

Comment: It's probably so hard for security reasons. (Assuming your local PC has a mic, would you want someone to be able to surreptitiously connect to your PC and eavesdrop on your mic? I know Remote Desktop is not exactly a surreptitious connection, but for hackers, a surreptitious connection is not that far removed from it.)

Answer (score 1):

People have claimed that it is doable and works via registry change:

From [bloogish.com](http://bloogish.com/285/remote-desktop-microphone-redirection/), [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=2020918), [Device and Resource Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc725887(v=ws.10).aspx)

However I have tested it on 2 of my Win7 Pro SP1 x64 laptops. The registry change is not working, even after reboot and confirmed the registry are 0. Please try and let us know result.

Alternatively, use Skype with auto answer on remote machine...

Comment: You've missed the point of the question.  I want to use the remote PC's microphone, not redirect the mic from the connecting computer to the remote computer.  I want computer "A" to remote-desktop into computer "B" and make "B" record from "B"'s own microphone.

Comment: If you are to use the mic at the remote machine, use [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/) instead. But this won't bring remote audio to your local computer.